# is it possble to split saving data automatically?

Tags: python, django

i have created 2 table, A and B. is it possible to split the data by choice? i have an rest api which can post delete and update . i am trying to save my data sperately and automatically like when i insert my data by giving the choice value typeA or typeB ,if its typeA it save the data to the A table if its typeB then save it to B table and when i change my data to typeA from typeB it moves the whole data to B table. is it possible?

models.py
`

```
class LoadType(models.Model):
    load = [
        ('a','typeA'),
        ('b','typeB')
    ]
    load_type = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=load)


class A(models.Model):
    code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    load_type = models.ForeignKey(LoadType,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    load_no = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    material_no = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    move_type = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    start_area = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    start_point = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    end_area = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    end_point = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    priority = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class B(models.Model):
    code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    load_type = models.ForeignKey(LoadType,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    load_no = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    material_no = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    move_type = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    start_area = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    start_point = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    swap_area = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    swap_point = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    end_area = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    end_point = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    priority = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

`
views.py

```
class PalletAPIView(APIView):

def post(self,request):
    serializer = PalletSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        event = Post_successed()
        
        return JsonResponse({"code":event.code,"detail":event.description},status=event.status,safe=False) 

    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
def put(self,request,format=None):
    try:
        data= request.data
        Pallet_Mission.objects.filter(Code=data['code']).update(load_no=data['load_no'],quantity=data['quantity'],move_type=data['move_type'],start_area=data['start_area']
        ,start_point=data['start_point'],end_area=data['end_area'],end_point=data['end_point'])
        event = Put_successed()
        return JsonResponse({"code":event.code,"detail":event.description},status=event.status,safe=False) 

    except Exception:
        return Response( status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST) 

def delete(self,request):
    try:
        data = request.data
        Pallet_Mission.objects.filter(code=data['code']).delete()
        event = Delete_successed()
        return JsonResponse({"code":event.code,"detail":event.description},status=event.status,safe=False)

    except Exception:
        return Response( status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Not sure if i need to add a new form or add some function ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have an rest api which can post delete and update . i am trying to save my data sperately and automatically like when i insert my data by giving the choice value typeA or typeB ,if its typeA it save the data to the A table if its typeB then save it to B table and when i change my data to typeA from typeB it moves the whole data to B table. is it possible?

Comment: `A` and `B` seem very similar with `B` only having 2 extra fields, you might want to do some normalization first.

Comment: what if A and B is the same just different load_type?

Comment: If they are the same with just the load type being different, why have separate models (tables in the DB) for them? Just have a field that stores the load type.